# Проблема с настройкой сервера под PHP

Tags: php, openserver

Установил `Open Server` для работы с `PHP`.
Настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код который не работает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo 'Привет от PHP'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

По идее должно вывести "Привет от PHP", но этого не произошло.

И вот такая ошибка в браузере:

> SyntaxError: illegal character

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На подробнее щелкните, что покажет?

Comment: Код, который вы показываете находится в `.php` файле или вы в html пытаетесь вызвать функцию `php`?

Comment: @RifmaMan, в html файле, скинул код. Расширение .html

Comment: @RifmaMan, когда я поменял расширение на .php вот что произошло: http://prntscr.com/jdj052
Браузер по какой-то причине просто закомментировал php код, но ошибка пропала

Comment: А переходите вы по адресу? htttp://localhost/

Comment: @RifmaMan, а да, действительно. я случайно локально открыл))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы php скриптов необходимо сохранять файлы с расширением .php или вносить соответствующуу запись в .htaccess (чтобы файлы .html воспринимались как php скрипты)

Comment: Вот результат, если записать тоже самое в файл с расширением .php
http://prntscr.com/jdj052

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  попробуйте удалить весь html код, оставить только php